# PowerBI Fetch data in multiple steps

Tags: rest, powerbi

I have a Web API that returns me data from different accounts (about 12 total). I can specify a date range in the API Query as well as the account.

I want to fetch 2 years of data from all accounts, then have an incremental refresh to load the latest data.

The issue I have is fetching 2 years of data for all accounts will put a big load on the server, which is not acceptable. I would like to do the initial fetch in multiple smaller steps. I had 2 ideas:

```
1. Fetch 2 years of data for one account, then the next, etc...
2. Fetch 2 months of data for all acounts, the the next 2, until today.
```

I don't know if either of those things are possible to do in PowerBI, I tried making multiples queries and appending them, but it seems at the "Apply steps", all queries are evaluated at the same time.

Is there a way to make multiple queries at different times, and have them all as one dataset in PowerBI?

Thanks!